# scrollTop using computed in vue.js

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs3

Here is part of my code

```js
<template>
  <button v-show="visible" @click="backToTop"></button>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
export default {
  computed: {
    visible() {
      return document.documentElement.scrollTop != 0
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

The button doesn't disappear when i scroll the page to the top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to listen to scroll event, try like following snippet:

```js
const app = Vue.createApp({
  data() {
    return {
      visible: false
    }
  },
  methods: {
    handleScroll (event){
      this.visible = window.scrollY != 0 ? true : false
    },
    backToTop() {
      window.scrollTo({
        top: 0,
        left: 0,
        behavior: 'smooth'
      })
    }
  },
  created () {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
  },
  destroyed () {
    window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
  },
})
app.mount('#demo')
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tailwindcss/2.2.19/tailwind.min.css" integrity="sha512-wnea99uKIC3TJF7v4eKk4Y+lMz2Mklv18+r4na2Gn1abDRPPOeef95xTzdwGD9e6zXJBteMIhZ1+68QC5byJZw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <p>x</p><p>x</p><p>x</p><p>x</p>
  <button v-show="visible" @click="backToTop"></button>
  <p>x</p><p>x</p><p>x</p><p>x</p><p>x</p><p>x</p><p>x</p><p>x</p><p>x</p><p>x</p><p>x</p><p>x</p><p>x</p><p>x</p><p>x</p><p>x</p><p>x</p><p>x</p><p>x</p><p>x</p>
</div>
```

Comment: it works, thank you. But why visible in computed didn' t work?

Comment: I don't know if this is too obvious but the window.scrollTo cannot be used in the template as an instrucion and must instead be called through a function. Or at least this is what I found out after some testing.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
window.scrollY
```

this will detect scrolling your document and it's value changes based on the current scroll position

for accessing the scroll height of your window, you need to access window instead of document